# Why is prometheus operator not able to start

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, prometheus, google-kubernetes-engine, prometheus-operator

I'm trying to  create prometheus with operator in fresh new k8s cluster
I use the following files ,

1. I’m creating a namespace  monitoring
2. Apply this file , which works ok

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: prometheus-operator
  name: prometheus-operator
  namespace: monitoring
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: prometheus-operator
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: prometheus-operator
    spec:
      priorityClassName: "operator-critical"
      tolerations:
      - key: "WorkGroup"
        operator: "Equal"
        value: "operator"
        effect: "NoSchedule"
      - key: "WorkGroup"
        operator: "Equal"
        value: "operator"
        effect: "NoExecute"
      containers:
      - args:
        - --kubelet-service=kube-system/kubelet
        - --logtostderr=true
        - --config-reloader-image=quay.io/coreos/configmap-reload:v0.0.1
        - --prometheus-config-reloader=quay.io/coreos/prometheus-config-reloader:v0.29.0
        image: quay.io/coreos/prometheus-operator:v0.29.0
        name: prometheus-operator
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          name: http
        securityContext:
          allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
          readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
      nodeSelector:
      serviceAccountName: prometheus-operator
```

Now I want  to apply this file (CRD)

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: Prometheus
metadata:
  name: prometheus
  namespace: monitoring
  labels: 
    prometheus: prometheus
spec:
  replica: 1
  priorityClassName: "operator-critical"
  serviceAccountName: prometheus
  nodeSelector:
        worker.garden.sapcloud.io/group: operator
  serviceMonitorNamespaceSelector: {}
  serviceMonitorSelector:
    matchLabels:
      role: observeable
  tolerations:
  - key: "WorkGroup"
    operator: "Equal"
    value: "operator"
    effect: "NoSchedule"
  - key: "WorkGroup"
    operator: "Equal"
    value: "operator"
    effect: "NoExecute"
```

before I've created those CRD

https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/tree/master/example/prometheus-operator-crd

The problem that the **pods didn't able to start** (0/2), see the picture below. What could be the problem?  please advice

[image]

**update**

when I go to the event of the prom operator I see the following Error `creating: pods "prometheus-operator-6944778645-" is forbidden: no PriorityClass with name operator-critical was found replicaset-controller` , any idea ?

Comment: what does this have to do with amazon-web-services?

Comment: Can you see log of the pods or events in the namespace?

Comment: @Tempux - when I go to the event of the prom operator I see the following `Error creating: pods "prometheus-operator-6944778645-" is forbidden: no PriorityClass with name operator-critical was found
replicaset-controller` , any idea ?

Comment: @kenlukas - well, my cluster is built on top aws...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to reference the `operator-critical` [priority class](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/pod-priority-preemption/#priorityclass). Priority classes determine the priority of pods and their resource assignment.

To fix this issue you could either remove the explicit priority class(`priorityClassName: "operator-critical"`) in both files or create the `operator-critical` class:

```
apiVersion: scheduling.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: PriorityClass
metadata:
  name: operator-critical
value: 1000000
globalDefault: false
description: "Critical operator workloads"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I've one question , when you provide limits for memory and cpu , what is it mean to define the request in prom ? for example if I define `limit` cpu "80000mi" and memory "160000", and request the same, does it provide high load on the system? can I limit the prom requests somehow to reduce the system load ?

Comment: @JennyM The `limit` will only apply if your Prometheus server experiences load. You can reduce the limit to also reduce the system load caused by Prometheus but this will not affect other workloads. For more information about requests and limits see https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/#how-pods-with-resource-requests-are-scheduled

Comment: Thanks, my question is a bit different maybe I didn't explain myself well, is there a way to limit the Prometheus  scraping loads, not sure if this is via request property or other prom property , currently we have hign lods system and even I provide lots of memory and cpu the like 32gb ram and 16cores we see that prom is working hard...

Comment: There is no limit you can define but you can reduce the load on Prometheus by either reducing the scrapping frequency or number of label values.

Comment: this is what I need, how can I reduce scrape frequency?

Comment: it will be great if you can provide some example :) thanks

Comment: You need to adjust the `interval` setting in the endpoints of your ServiceMonitors (https://coreos.com/operators/prometheus/docs/latest/api.html#endpoint). You can see the ServiceMonitors using kubectl: `kubectl get all servicemonitor --all-namespaces`

Answer (score -1):

Prometheus and alert manager pods need persistent volume to store the data. Make sure those pv's are present and are bound to the respective pods. Alternatively you can make those pods ephemeral. It should work

Comment: How can I define it ? please provide the steps for your suggestion and i'll try

Comment: when I go to the event of the prom operator I see the following Error `creating: pods "prometheus-operator-6944778645-" is forbidden: no PriorityClass with name operator-critical was found replicaset-controller ,` any idea how to solve it ?

Comment: The issue isn't related to PVs or storage classes

Comment: initially prom operator didn't work for me. I made prom and alert manager pods as ephemeral. it runs without issues on my cluster